# collection_selection to create local variable in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a rails form that will pass a local variable back to a controller, using a collection_select call, and am generating errors that I can't for the life of me work out.

The form is in the Network#new view. The collection_select should create a drop down menu of existing superusers, so the new network can be assigned a superuser (via a superuser_id) on creation. The Network#create method knows how to deal with the  superuser_id. So my form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@network) do |f| %>
  <%=render(partial: 'edit_form', locals: {f: f} ) %>

  <% fields_for 'superuser_id', url: {action: :create} do |su| %>
    <div>
      <%= su.label 'Network Superuser' %>
      <%= su.collection_select( 'superuser_id',@superusers, :id, :user_name)  %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

The error I get is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `superuser_id' for {:url=>{:action=>:create}}:Hash):
6:   <% fields_for 'superuser_id', url: {action: :create}  do |su| %>
7:      <div>
8:        <%= su.label 'Network Superuser' %>
9:        <%= su.collection_select( 'superuser_id', @superusers, :id, :user_name)  %>
app/views/networks/new.html.erb:9:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_networks_new_html_erb__687644901_79475060'
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields_for` is designed to handle a sub form of a relationship, and so it is usually used like `fields_for :supervisor` without the _id.  However, it looks like this is a `:belongs_to` relationship, and `fields_for` is completely unneeded. You aren't trying to create a form to edit the attributes of the supersuser, you are only assigning an existing id to the network object.

Try: `<%= f.collection_select( 'superuser_id',@superusers, :id, :user_name)  %>` without the fields_for block

Comment: Thanks DGM. However, superuser_id is a local variable, not a member of Network (it is actually a user ID and will be used to create a Permission object in a HABTM relationship between users and networks). So I still need to do a collection_select to create a local variable that can then be used to create the Permission from.

Comment: In that case, you have two choices: don't use the form builder `f.` but rather a plain `input_tag` and collect the value from params in your controller, or better, *make* it an attribute of network.  A virtual attribute.  You could define `superuser_id` and `superuser_id=` in your network model, and put the the code to build your permissions there.  I suspect that would also clean up your controller.

Comment: Hmm - second options sounds like it might have some mileage ... I'll think about this. Cheers Steve

Comment: or at the very least, put the code to build the permissions in another class, and use the virtual attributes to call it. :)